# Pandas Dataframe: How to select a row by index, and then get the next few rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, I have a Dataframe indexed by timestamp. Looks like the following table:

```
                 A      B     C     D  
DATE                                                             
2018-01-17        157.52        163.74       157.28         159.84   
2018-01-16        158.25        159.35       155.93         157.40   
2018-01-15        157.15        159.59       156.79         158.86   
2018-01-12        158.25        158.62       157.40         157.52
```

And I'm trying to select a row by index, and also select the next few rows. (For example, select two rows start at 2018-01-12). I found both .loc and .iloc are hard to do such task. Is there any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution **#1**: Using the DataFrame's index, followed by `head(2)`:

```python
df['2018-01-12':].head(2)
```

Solution **#2**: Using `iloc`:

```
i = df.index.get_loc('2018-01-12')
df.iloc[i:i+2]
```

Bonus solution **#3**: It seems like you're analyzing stock data. Maybe you're interested in something that could be more efficiently done using rolling windows? (Moving Averages maybe?) Consider using [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), e.g. to calculate the rolling mean:

```
df.rolling(2).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like:

```
date_of_wanted_row = "2018-01-12"
iloc_of_wanted_row = df.index.get_loc(date_of_wanted_row)
return df.iloc[iloc_of_wanted_row: iloc_of_wanted_row + 4]
```

(but with more sensible variable names, and I'm assuming the dates in the index are not really strings)

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using [numpy.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html).

```
loc = df.index.get_loc(row)
print(df.loc[np.r_[loc:loc+2], :])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use (to get values between dates):

```
df.loc['2018-01-12':'2018-01-14']
```

or, to get all data from January:

```
df.loc['2018-01']
```